# IE creating a phantom div in a listing loop

Tags: asp-classic, cross-browser

I've been working on this for a few days now and cannot find a solution.

http://mri.sniperdyne.com/inventory.asp?CatId=C547E3B5-44F4-4BB5-BF2D-CE51BB8E8DA6

In FF the loop works fine. In IE8 it creates a phantom div at the top. Has anyone seen this before?

The background programming language is ASP with VB.

I'm not sure if this is something that is caused by cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

When I have problems like this, it's usually an indication that I forgot to close a div somewhere. Or I closed one too many. If it's not obvious when you eyeball the code, try running the page through the [W3C Validator Service](http://validator.w3.org/) to find and fix any markup problems.

Comment: Thanks! I had a dynamic breadcrumb that was generating anchors that weren't closing, which somehow created the phantom div. I give you and up one but my reputation isn't at 15 yet. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Even if you can't vote, you can accept the answer. Helps to keep SO cleaner.